# Failed to launch a project in eclipse, got "Launch error"

Tags: java, eclipse, launch, sonarlint

I would like to change my `JDK` from 1.8 to 1.16, So I uninstalled my `JDK 8` and installed `JDK 16`, Installation is succeeded but whenever I try to Launch my project in eclipse, I got a [IllegalStateException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otSEY.jpg) error.
Here I got an error while opening eclipse.
Please give me some solutions.

Comment: You need to show us more of the log - as text please, not images. What version of Eclipse? Older versions of Eclipse won't work with Java 9 or later. The log suggests an issue with Sonarlint - what version of that? Does that version support newer versions of Java?

Comment: Eclipse version: 2020-03 (4.15.0), Sonarlint version: 5.2.0.18685, I think you are right, maybe my sonarlint version is not matching  to JDK version, Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Note: If you actually want to use the new features of Java 16 you need Eclipse 2021-03 with a patch (or Eclipse 2021-06 when it comes out next month).